# Create auto policy in PolicyCenter via webservice

Tags: guidewire

Guidewire PolicyCenter 10.2 self managed. I'd like to create and quote submission for auto policy line.

1. Is there a rest api for submission creation exposed via the policy center? Based on the documentation I've an impression it should be there but swagger ui doesn't show related api
2. I found only soap based web service. Now coming to submission api I see it's very generic, it looks policyPeriodData should be a raw xml that contains all the data about drivers, vehicles etc. How can I get such template in an easy way?

Edit:
Using gosu scratchpad I was able to generate sample xml for policy period
`var pp = new gw.webservice.pc.pc1000.gxmodel.policyperiodmodel.PolicyPeriod(pd) print(pp.asUTFString())`
it contains drivers data but I don't see any api how to pass vehicles data

Comment: if your license from GW allows that there's a quote and buy API - in v9 that was json based. This was intended for Portals, but you could use it. I believe you should be able to download it from GW Market place if you have access. Try asking GW support for that if you have anyone on site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-managed versions of PolicyCenter do not expose functional OOTB REST APIs, they only come with the REST framework to create new APIs. Only the PolicyCenter cloud releases come with functionally complete OOTB APIs.